# Database Schema design of server running status log

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I am working with 4 AWS EC2 instances (servers). Each Instance has `Instance ID` and `Instance Name`. `Instance ID` is unique. Each of them having multiple application servers, like on of them is running `PUMA` server and another one is running `NGINX` and so on. I want to store the running status of the instances and their application servers in a database.

Like, If Instance A is running or not, that I can get by continuously hitting into the exposed port and store it in the database. I am scanning it in each minute. There will be 3 columns I can think of right now,

Instance A :-

```
Instance ID    Running Status   Time

Instance A        Running        10:10:04
Instance A        Running        10:11:04
Instance A        Running        10:12:04
```

Next, I want to store the status if Application Servers within `Instance A` running or not. There will be 3 columns I can think of right now,

Let's say `PUMA` and `NGINX` are running in `Instance A`

Instance A :- (Here also I am scanning it in each minute)

```
Application Name   Running Status   Time

PUMA                  Running       12:10:20
NGINX                 Running       12:10:20
PUMA                  Running       12:11:20
NGINX                 Running       12:11:20
```

I am using Postgresql. What will be the recommended schema design here ? Should I create a table for each instance and how will I map the applications with that particular Instance ? If I take Instance ID as a primary key then duplicate values in that column are not possible.

Comment: with your 3 columns set PK will be on two columns I suppose - same instance same time can be either running or not

Comment: set "Instance ID" as a PK ? but "Instance ID" value have duplicate values, if I manage in one table.

Comment: How many inserts/sec?  What do the selects look like?  Removing `[mysql]` since it seems to be irrelevant.